# Refresh page very long with Nginx as reverse proxy for Express and NuxtJs

Tags: express, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I configured my server with nginx as a reverse proxy for a Nuxt/Express SSR application. For the moment I have a login page, and a home page.

I can connect and disconnect without any problem.

However, when I'm connected and I refresh the page, the loading time is very long.

I don't know if this is due to Nginx configuration or the authentication API or redirection.

I've noticed that it also happens when I type my url myself in the address bar.

Thanks in advance for your help

Update : 
Here is my nginx config

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map_hash_max_size 64;
    map_hash_bucket_size 64;
    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        "text/html"                 epoch;
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
        default                     off;
    }

    server {
        listen       9998 ssl;
        server_name  control.serenicity.fr;

        ssl_certificate      "C:/nginx-1.19.0/ssl/mydomain.fr.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key  "C:/nginx-1.19.0/ssl/mydomain.fr.key";


        location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://10.0.5.11:3000; 
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the request when I refresh :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PeHzCaHvLNL8_YN9ZOEFNv_gxQe2jpu9/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b9m3cDL_LOv1d3Kaaucnq4Qi308P8TLT/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xe_EBnb_XXWo7IlaI47EtlaLE6eFgd2k/view?usp=sharing

Update 2 :

After several hours of debugging, it seems that there is no link with nginx. 
The problem comes from nuxt in SSR. When I disable SSR there is no more problem.

Comment: Please show your nginx config.

Comment: And a screenshot of requests and responses from browser dev console